# Ask justify in php with wordwrap

Tags: php, html, justify

i use wordwrap function php but i want make line by line is justify..
this is my simple code :

```
<?php
$text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software.';

$pish = wordwrap($text, 60, '|', 1);
$psh =explode('|',$pish);

echo $psh[0]."<br>";
echo $psh[1]."<br>";
for($i=2;$i<10;++$i){
    echo $psh[$i]."<br>";
}

?>
```

results kode :

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
software.
```

How to make that justify?

i want result :

```
Lorem  Ipsum  is  simply  dummy  text  of  the  printing and
typesetting  industry.  Lorem  Ipsum  has been the industrys
standard  dummy  text  ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
printer  took a galley  of  type  and scrambled it to make a
type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
but  also  the  leap  into electronic typesetting, remaining
essentially  unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
the  release  of  Letraset  sheets  containing  Lorem  Ipsum
passages,   and   more   recently  with  desktop  publishing
software.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this using css. If css using is ok for you then try the below code. hope this will help you.

CSS

```
<style>
.fulljustify {
   text-align: justify;
   width:408px;
}
.fulljustify:after {
   content: "";
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

php code

```
<?php
 $text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software.';
 $pish = wordwrap($text, 60, '|', 1);
 $psh =explode('|',$pish);
 echo "<div class='fulljustify'>";
 echo $psh[0]."</div>";
 echo "<div class='fulljustify'>".$psh[1]."</div>";
 for($i=2;$i<10;++$i){
  echo "<div class='fulljustify'>".$psh[$i]."</div>";
 }
?>
```

Comment: thanks @Azeez Kallayi , but thats still can't make justify >.<

Comment: can you share me the link where you uploaded the script.

Comment: i upload on localhost :/

Comment: I have uploaded the script in to my test folder and it seems working fine.  http://azeezkallayi.com/demo/test/justify.php

Comment: oh, sorry, my div is inside on the table :/
so thats be <table><tr><td><div class="fulljustify"></div></td></tr> but cannot make justify.